# PostEntityImage in update message post-operartion has no key at all

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have registered a plugin for update message of some entity (in post-operation) via CRM tool in Visual Studio and also registered post-image for that plugin like below:

[image]

[image]

and here is my code :

> protected void ExecutePostOpportunityUpdate(LocalPluginContext
>   localContext)
>           {
>
> ```
>         if (localContext == null)
>         {
>             throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
>         }
>
>
>
>
>         // TODO: Implement your custom Plug-in business logic.
>         IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
>
>         Entity postImage = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];
> ```
>
> ....
>
> }

But it throws an error and says that there is no key in PostEntityImages at all. I debugged the plugin and saw that there is no key in that at all.

Would you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at your code you have to retrieve the actual entity of Opportunity: Try this

```
 try
 {

Entity postOpportunityService = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];

// Opportunity service's parent opportunity lookup reference
EntityReference opportunityReference = (EntityReference)postOpportunityService.Attributes["mpc_opportunityid"];

// Columns to be retrieved for opportunity (aka. columns to be edited)
ColumnSet opportunityColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "estimatedvalue", "mpc_estoneoffinvoicing", "mpc_estinvoicingperyear" });

// Retrieve actual opportunity entity
Entity opportunity = service.Retrieve(opportunityReference.LogicalName, opportunityReference.Id, opportunityColumnSet);             

}

catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex) {   tracingService.Trace("FaultException", ex.ToString()); }
```

Comment: Thanks....It may seems ridicules but restarting the crm server solved the problem and now PreImage and PostImage are filled!

Comment: Wellcome yeah it sometimes happens to me also. Recycling the crm apppool does the work and it is one of the gOOD practices. :D